# Compare adding constraints in autolayout Vs setting autoresizing in IB Inspector

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-autolayout

In xcode, I recently have a look at autoresizing in IB inspector. But I didn't get its actual use. How its different from adding constraints in autolayout?

Answer (score 2):

**AutoLayout** (deals with external constraints.) **vs**   **Autoresizing**  (deals with internal content.)

In simple language  Autoresizing is about that how the contents of a view will fit in the view. It means it depends on the content of the view.

where as  AutoLayout is about how the external constraints for example  position of the view , the size of view supported  by   other neighboring  components.

AutoLayout actually triggers the  AutoResizing Task and  for autoresizing activity   , auto-layout  forcefully or normally change or break  the default constraints  of views which are related to the corresponding view if needed.